# Передача текста через Buf с помощью Socket

Tags: delphi, сокет, delphi-10-berlin

Передаю текст

```
var
  s: String;
  I: Integer;
begin
  if ClientSocket1.Active then
  begin
    s := ETransfer.Text;
    I := Length(s);
    ClientSocket1.Socket.SendBuf(s, SizeOf(I));
  end;
end;
```

Получаю текст

```
var
  s: String;
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := Socket.ReceiveLength;
  SetLength(s, I);
  Socket.ReceiveBuf(s, I);
  EReceiving.Text := s;
end;
```

Тип сокета stNonBlocking

Делал передачу 12 раз, каждый раз передавая на один символ больше получаю проблему на картинке ниже.
Чем больше текст тем хуже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чуть позже нашёл такой способ

```
procedure TFormMain.BSendClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bfr: PChar;
begin
  if ClientSocket1.Active then
  begin
    Bfr := PChar(ETransfer.Text);
    ClientSocket1.Socket.SendBuf(Bfr^, Length(ETransfer.Text));
  end;
end;
 
procedure TFormMain.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  s: String;
begin
  SetLength(s, Socket.ReceiveLength);
  SetLength(s, Socket.ReceiveBuf(Pointer(s)^, Length(s)));
  EReceiving.Text := s;
end;
```

Работает, но доверия не вселяет.

Comment: А что за проблему можно увидеть на картинке?

Comment: Отправка происходит не каждый раз. На скрине показано, что текст приходит только после отправки количества символов: 1, 4, 8, 12.

Comment: `SizeOf(I)` - это что делает?

Comment: Интересно, что `работает`, при том, что SendBuf требует количества байтов, что не совсем то, что длина строки

Comment: Передача строки: `ClientSocket1.Socket.SendBuf(s[1], Length(s));`. Но есть одна проблема: tcp передаёт данные в потоке, т.е. если вы отправляете две строки, например длиной 10 символов и 6 символов, то на выходе вы можете получить строку длиной 16 символов или две, длиной по 8, или любые другие варианты с суммарной длиной в 16 символов.